# convert into date format oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a field `c_days` in the table `my_table` that accepts numeric values ​​from 1 to 31.
In this field, numbers from 1 to 9 are single digits.

I am writing a condition, if `c_day` is greater than today, then you need to display `c_day` in the `to_date` date format, if less, then display `c_day` in the date format, only the next month.

For example, `c_day` is 14, and today we have the 8th number, so you need to display the date 14.02.2023, If `c_day` is equal to 5, then you need to display the date of the next month 05.03.2023

I did something like this:

```
SELECT 
   C_DAY,
   CASE
     WHEN C_DAY >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN 
       TO_DATE(C_DAY || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     WHEN C_DAY < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN
       TO_DATE(C_DAY || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     WHEN C_DAY IS NULL THEN
       null
   END AS new_field
FROM my_table
```

The problem is that the end result is not converted to the date format, I thought it's cause of that the dates can be displayed as 1.03.2023, 7.03.2023, so i tried convert it into

```
TO_CHAR(C_DAY, 'fm00')
```

and did this:

```
SELECT 
   C_DAY,
   CASE
     WHEN TO_CHAR(C_DAY, 'fm00') >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(C_DAY, 'fm00') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     WHEN TO_CHAR(C_DAY, 'fm00') < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(C_DAY, 'fm00') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM') || '.' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy')
     WHEN C_DAY IS NULL THEN
       null
   END AS new_field
FROM my_table
```

But its not even working, it shows ora error

Comment: Look at your code. No matter whether `C_DAY` is bigger than `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD')` or not, you return the same expression! You can also write it shorter `TO_DATE(C_DAY ||  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, '.MM.YYYY'), 'DD.MM.YYYY')`

Comment: Of course, it is converted to a `DATE` value, otherwise you would get an error. Maybe you are not happy with the (default) **display** format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without any string-to-date (or vice-versa) conversions using:

```sql
SELECT C_DAY,
       LEAST(
         ADD_MONTHS(
           TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),
           CASE WHEN c_day <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
         ) + c_day - 1,
         LAST_DAY(
           ADD_MONTHS(
             TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'),
             CASE WHEN c_day <= EXTRACT(DAY FROM SYSDATE) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
           )
         )
       ) AS new_field
FROM   my_table
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table(c_day) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31;
```

Outputs:

| C_DAY | NEW_FIELD |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-02-03 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 2023-02-04 00:00:00 |
| 5 | 2023-02-05 00:00:00 |
| 6 | 2023-02-06 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 2023-02-07 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 2023-02-08 00:00:00 |
| 9 | 2023-03-09 00:00:00 |
| 10 | 2023-03-10 00:00:00 |
| 11 | 2023-03-11 00:00:00 |
| 12 | 2023-03-12 00:00:00 |
| 13 | 2023-03-13 00:00:00 |
| 14 | 2023-03-14 00:00:00 |
| 15 | 2023-03-15 00:00:00 |
| 16 | 2023-03-16 00:00:00 |
| 17 | 2023-03-17 00:00:00 |
| 18 | 2023-03-18 00:00:00 |
| 19 | 2023-03-19 00:00:00 |
| 20 | 2023-03-20 00:00:00 |
| 21 | 2023-03-21 00:00:00 |
| 22 | 2023-03-22 00:00:00 |
| 23 | 2023-03-23 00:00:00 |
| 24 | 2023-03-24 00:00:00 |
| 25 | 2023-03-25 00:00:00 |
| 26 | 2023-03-26 00:00:00 |
| 27 | 2023-03-27 00:00:00 |
| 28 | 2023-03-28 00:00:00 |
| 29 | 2023-03-29 00:00:00 |
| 30 | 2023-03-30 00:00:00 |
| 31 | 2023-03-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WAZeKvkO)

Comment: It's works, thanks man, i have the same question, can u help?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> WITH
  2     my_table (c_day)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 14 FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 5 FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 30 FROM DUAL)
  9  SELECT c_day,
 10         TO_DATE (
 11               LPAD (LEAST (c_day, TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY (SYSDATE), 'dd')), 2, '0')
 12            || '.'
 13            || TO_CHAR (
 14                  CASE
 15                     WHEN c_day < TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'dd')
 16                     THEN
 17                        ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 1)
 18                     ELSE
 19                        SYSDATE
 20                  END,
 21                  'mm.yyyy'),
 22            'dd.mm.yyyy') AS result
 23    FROM my_table;

     C_DAY RESULT
---------- ----------
        14 14.02.2023
         5 05.03.2023
        30 28.02.2023

SQL>
```

Comment: another error ora-01858

Comment: By the way, there is also such a case, February ends on the 28th, and if c_day is equal to 29, 30, 31, maybe because of this I get an error, how can I avoid this?

Comment: What do you want to do in such a case?

Comment: I set it to last day of the current month; see edited code.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I try to use your select with my main table, I get an error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected. I output all unique values, these are numbers from 1 to 31 and null

Comment: Are you sure you used **exactly** code I posted? It looks as if you used different date format model (e.g. using month NAME (such as DD-MON-YYYY) and not its number (such as DD.MM.YYYY)).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251721/discussion-between-andrey-romanov-and-littlefoot).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, one solution could be this one

```
SELECT 
   C_DAY,
   CASE
     WHEN C_DAY >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN 
       ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-')||C_DAY , 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1)
     WHEN C_DAY < TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD') THEN
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-')||C_DAY , 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   END AS new_field
FROM my_table
```

The `ADD_MONTHS` function works as this:

> If `date` is the last day of the month or if the resulting month has fewer days than the day component of `date`, then the result is the last day of the resulting month. Otherwise, the result has the same day component as `date`.

Comment: I *think* that "day" component must reflect value of C_DAY column, not SYSDATE.

Comment: @Littlefoot correct, I updated it. But it still needs some fine-tuning if `C_DAY` is greater than number of days of current month. Your answer is better!

Comment: Now, khm, it won't work if C_DAY = 30 (as February doesn't have that many days) :)