# Months that ends with 29,30,31 ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

[convert into date format oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75382316/convert-into-date-format-oracle) there is an identical question in the continuation of this discussion.

I have a field `c_day` in the table `my_table` that accepts numeric values ​​from 1 to 31. In this field. I need to add 210 days to today's date, and insert the value from `c_day` from the released date dd.mm.yyyy. For example, we take today's date `08.02.2023` and add 210 days to it, the date falls on September, and if `c_day` is 20, then the output should be `20.09.2023`. But if `c_day`is equal to 31, then of course the date should be set as `30.09.2023`, because the last day of September is 30.

Now I settled on cases where September ends on the 30th, and the field takes values ​​from 1 to 31. How can I write a condition in such cases so that it takes the last day of the month?

I tried this one, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
  C_DAY,
  LEAST(
   TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 210, 'YYYY-MM-') || C_DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
   CASE 
  WHEN C_DAY < TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 210), 'DD') THEN
    last_day(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 210, 'YYYY-MM-') || C_DAY, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
   END 
   ) as  result
FROM MY_TABLE
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Why 210 days - if that is a rough approximation, can you do `add_months(sysdate, 7))` instead? (The `trunc()` isn't really doing anything, since you lose the time when you convert to a string anyway.)

Comment: `least(extract(day from last_day(whatever + x)), c_day)`?

Comment: @AlexPoole If we take for example 01.01.2023 and add 210 days it will be 30.07.2023, but if the date is already a couple of days longer, starting from 03.01.2023 
and adding 210 days, the date will fall on August, it will be erroneous to add 7 months at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can do it without any string manipulation using:

```sql
SELECT C_DAY,
       LEAST(
         TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 210, 'MM') + C_DAY - 1,
         LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 210)
       ) AS  result
FROM   MY_TABLE
ORDER BY c_day
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( c_day ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31;
```

Outputs:

| C_DAY | RESULT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-09-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-09-03 00:00:00 |
| ... | ... |
| 28 | 2023-09-28 00:00:00 |
| 29 | 2023-09-29 00:00:00 |
| 30 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 |
| 31 | 2023-09-30 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/UzzlYYNj)